# Create a whole structure with a file system?

Tags: coldfusion, directory, adobe, structure, cfml

Good morning,

I have a question, I'd like to create a struct with files and folders to make them accessible really quickly.

Let's say I have a X folder with Y and Z in it, and in Y, I have the blue file. Can you give me a lead on how to process the build of this system ?

For the result, I would like to access this label by doing X.Y.blue.

Thank you very much in advance.

Cheers.

Comment: What would these files contain?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Why not use `directoryList()` or the richer `<cfdirectory action="list">`? It basically returns everything you need to know about the filesystem structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, read some documentation about directoryList() and it works perfectly :) thank you everyone ! have a nice day